# How to duplicate virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have an existing virtualenv with a lot of packages but an old version of Django.

What I want to do is **duplicate** this environment so I have another environment with the exact same packages *but* a newer version of Django. How can I do this?

Comment: I would pip freeze all your requirements into a 'requirements.txt' file and create another virtualenv and run pip install requirements.txt

Comment: If the python version of the virtual environment that you want to copy is different from your default python environment, you can setup the new environment as `virtualenv -p /path/to/older/venv/bin/python new_venv` and then use the `requirements.txt` that you generated after `pip freeze`

Comment: @CalvinCheng it is "pip install -r requirements.txt"

Answer (score 248, accepted):

The easiest way is to use pip to generate a requirements file. A requirements file is basically a file that contains a list of all the python packages you want to install (or have already installed in case of file generated by pip), and what versions they're at.

To generate a requirements file, go into your original virtualenv, and run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will generate the *requirements.txt* file for you. If you open that file up in your favorite text editor, you'll see something like:

```
Django==1.3
Fabric==1.0.1
etc...
```

Now, edit the line that says `Django==x.x` to say `Django==1.3` (or whatever version you want to install in your new virtualenv).

Lastly, activate your **new** virtualenv, and run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And pip will automatically download and install all the python modules listed in your *requirements.txt* file, at whatever versions you specified!

Comment: what if I copy the folder and then paste it on another machine? It would work? Assuming of course the apt-get dependencies were resolved

Comment: Indeed it does not, as I am finding out just now.

Comment: I see many messages `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement a_package=#.#.#` Can I solve it easily? I removed a line or changed the equality to the inequality.

Comment: Works for `pyenv` as well. Awesome answer.

Comment: So far, it sounds like being the best approach for me.

Comment: virtualenv-clone worked well for me (answer below) and didn't require recompiling opencv and installing in the new virtualenv.  Having said that, requirements.txt is a good answer for more generic environments.

Comment: the virtualenv-clone although working seems to retain (in Ubuntu) the name of the old virtualenv in the command prompt.

Comment: It works! Pay attention with PyTorch. You have to remove the line where it has been declared in requirements.txt and all its extensions, otherwise it raises an error. You will need to install it from the official command provided by its site

Comment: I won't work if packages are not available on PyPI. For example, if your Python venv has Nvidia Modulus installed.

Comment: `pip install -r path\to\requirements.txt`

Answer (score 39):

Another option is to use [`virtualenv-clone`](https://github.com/edwardgeorge/virtualenv-clone) package:

> A script for cloning a non-relocatable virtualenv.

Comment: Hi, am i right to assume this allows me to copy a WHOLE python environment into a file. Then i would just have to load this file in a new computer/OS and i would get all my site packages installed back

Comment: "virtualenv-clone source/ target/" worked like a charm thanks!

Comment: make sure we installed `virtualenv-clone` after activating the virtualenv

Comment: The syntax is `python -m clonevirtualenv source/ target/`

Comment: This has the benefit of copying opencv, which I had to install from source.  I could have done another full make with the new virtual env as the target, but this was a lot simpler.

Answer (score 20):

Easiest option is using [`virtualenv-clone`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv-clone/) package.

To duplicate `venv1` to `venv2`, follow these steps:

1. Install `virtualenv-clone` in either `venv1` or a dummy virtual environment `venv_dummy`. To create `venv_dummy`:

   ```
   python -m virtualenv venv_dummy
   source venv_dummy/bin/activate
   ```
2. To install `virtualenv-clone`:

   ```
   (venv_dummy): pip install virtualenv-clone
   ```
3. To duplicate `venv1` to `venv2`:

   ```
   (venv_dummy): virtualenv-clone venv1/ venv2/
   ```

Comment: the prompt in bash is not changes, have to edit bin/activate, and not 100% clear how

Comment: @MrR .. you don't have to edit `bin/activate` if you follow this answer. Why do you have to edit `bin/activate`?

Comment: After I've cloned, my prompt in bash had the original environment name, because of the PS1 section within `bin/activate`

Comment: @MrR That sounds like a bug or oversight in virtualenv-clone but one that shouldn't really affect behavior.

Comment: if the name is not changed according to @MrR, then go to the new environments `bin/activate` file and search for the old env name and set the new name. Voila! 
There will be 2 occurences to rename. Good Luck!!

Comment: Replace the block starting with `if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then` with [this](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzNNIVpBt0pBSaU6zDMoJNTRJ97VLyzexTPY0cnHNT4gyN83IES3VkkhVsFaoSQjNY9LAQji/X1c4mHqA4INbYHagRRQHVgabKhShZKCoq1CBapOEMDUkJpTnIoqrZGQlFicmpeYm6oQo6SC5LQYpQRNBRTNaZkQMyoK8otKQLq50jL//wcA)

Answer (score 18):

`virtualenvwrapper` provides a [command to duplicate virtualenv](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#cpvirtualenv)

```
cpvirtualenv ENVNAME [TARGETENVNAME]
```

Comment: Not really a good idea.

"Copying virtual environments is not well supported. Each virtualenv has path information hard-coded into it, and there may be cases where the copy code does not know it needs to update a particular file. Use with caution."

Comment: Can you specify a path to the venv instead of the name?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) you can just run:

```
conda create --name myclone --clone myenv
```

This will copy `myenv` to the newly created environment called `myclone`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my go to command for cloning python virtual environments.

```
packs=`source-path/bin/pip freeze` && python3 -m venv <env-name> && target-path/bin/pip install $packs
```

Conventions used in above command:

- source-path = path to env that you want to clone e.g. `/home/john/envs/oldenv`.
- env-name = name of the cloned env e.g. `myenv`, it can be a path as well e.g.
  `/home/john/envs/myenv`
- target-path = path to new cloned env e.g. `/home/john/envs/<env-name>`

Advantages of using this or why i prefer this

1. No need to generate a requirements.txt file.
2. No environment is activated/deactivated during cloning process.
3. single command to be executed(3 commands ran at once).

In some cases you might want to exclude global packages from while cloning env you can replace `source-path/bin/pip freeze` with `source-path/bin/pip freeze --local`, more about `--local` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931275/pip-freeze-local/54931519)

Answer (score 1):

In case you use pip "venv". I copy pasted the folder holding the virtual environment and manually changed the files in the bin folder of the copied folder.
I don't know if its efficient,but it works!

Comment: Hello Saai Sudarsanan D and welcome to StackOverflow! Please, have a read on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply:

- Copy the existing virtual env directory to a new one
- Update to the new Django?

Comment: Some times I use this approach, but has the inconvenience of having to update some paths inside the bin/activate script.

Comment: Is the change a simple find and replace on references to the env name, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: In my case, simply updating the path in the VIRTUAL_ENV constant in bin/activate did the trick

Comment: On the other hand, changing bin/activate is quite a hack, and one must wonder if this can break stuff at some point. Especially when virtual environments are used in production settings.

Comment: It does break a lot of things. It's easier to just recreate or clone the virtualenv. I tried to do just this (while waiting for a proxy server to open up so that I can reinstall all required packages and just start from scratch), and it ain't working! I thought I was being clever, but alas, it will take a lot of hacking to get this up and running, and honestly, there are much better things to do.

Comment: @minghua Your edit adds a lot to the answer, I suggest adding a separate answer instead of the edit.

Comment: This has indexing issues with the python environment that you are trying to setup on the server. When you just copy paste virtualenv directory directly onto your required system, some files in the Include folder have absolute paths to bind different components, and now because that changes on your new system. So though you will be able to activate this new env but not use its packages.

Comment: It is not just the bin/activate that needs to be fixed.  Look at the shabangs of the other scripts in bin/.   They point to the original venv's python path.  I would use the answer from @rdegges and freeze.

Answer (score 0):

pip works, but it's a problem on a computer without internet.

I wrote a small code for this, it worked for me. I'm writing it here because maybe it will be useful for someone else.

( Note: I tested it on Windows )

1. copy project folder
2. paste project folder to another directory
3. change the address parts in this code and run the code:

```
import os

# The new address of our script folder
script_folder = r'D:\Python proqrams\pdf_to_excel\venv\Scripts'

# the old address of our venv folder
old_path = rb'C:\Users\AVG-dell\Desktop\pdf_to_excel\venv'

# the new address of our venv folder
new_path = rb"D:\Python proqrams\pdf_to_excel\venv"


def find_replace( folder ):

    names = os.listdir( folder )

    for name in names:
        current_path = os.path.join( folder, name )

        if os.path.isdir( current_path ):
            find_replace( current_path )

        elif os.path.isfile( current_path ) :

            try:
                with open( current_path ,'rb' ) as f:
                    data = f.read()

                if old_path in data:
                    print( current_path )

                    data2 = data.replace( old_path , new_path )

                    with open( current_path , 'wb' ) as f:
                        f.write(data2)


            except:
                pass



find_replace( script_folder )

print('completed')
```