# Combining 2 projects with 1 virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I came up with the situation where I want to use 2 separate projects in tensorflow. The problem is that I use a (quite heavy loaded) virtual environment and I would like to keep using it. In those projects there are two folders named  (not too surprisingly) `utils`. So, I guess a conflict occurs when I import from the second folder.

Possible solutions that I could think of:

1. Create a new virtual environment or even better clone the existing one like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438681/duplicate-virtualenv) I guess. Con is that it takes about 1.7GB and I am running out of space (but I could deal with that somehow if that's the best choice).
2. Try to debug the conflicting cases using folder prefixes like instead of:
   `from utils import label_map_util` I could use `from project2.utils import label_map_util`. This seems to work but has the con that I must search every file for conflicting imports. Like inside `label_map_util.py` where a similar import crashes (there are various folders in the project).

Is there any better solution? Am I missing something obvious here?

Also (I am fairly new to python) should this conflict be dealt automatically by python? I mean when inside a module in a folder and trying to import another module existing in the same folder or subfolder shouldn't this get priority over modules in other parallel folders (possibly in other projects etc)?

Edit:

To make it more clear I have 2 projects say `projectA` and `projectB` meaning 2 folders with various subfolders, which both contains a folder named `utils`. `projectA` was running just fine before the installation of `projectB`.

When I installed `projectB` and tried to run a module in it it contained imports from `utils` folder. Like

```
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

etc. I am using pyCharm and my IDE did not recognized the import as valid. I tried to debug it in interactive mode and my conclusions were:

- There is a `label_map_util.py` module in folder `utils` in `projectB` folder.
- For some reason import tries to find this module in `projectA`. So, when there is no module with that name it complains giving error:

  > ImportError: cannot import name 'label_map_util'
- in that sense `import utils` works fine but imports the wrong module (from `projectA`).

Comment: You can use relative imports.

Comment: What are the actual issues you are experiencing?

Comment: The problem is that it does not import the second module and so it crashes when functions are not present.

Comment: I do not think that is enough of a description. I do not know what you are actually doing, what is your directory and file sctructure, what exception is raised, traceback, etc. Try to create a [mcve].