# Use venv create virtual environment, but find the new virtual environment shares same package files with older virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I use `python -m venv {new venv dir}` to create a virtual environment, but find the new virtual environment shares same package files with older virtual environment.

I want the new virtual environment totally deep copy the older virtual environment's packages. How could I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: something like this will it do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438681/how-to-duplicate-virtualenv

Comment: @phd.... but i tot he say deep-copy?

Comment: @user1538798 OMG yes you're right, my bad!