# Versions not found when installing from requirements-file with pip in venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, requirements

I want to make a 'copy' of my python virtual environment, which is a venv, in another directory (on a different machine) following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113607/how-to-clone-a-venv-virtual-environment). But I run into some problems for which I found no solution elsewhere and I don't know what happens:

**My steps:**
I do `pip freeze > venv_requirements.txt` and copy that file over to the other directory. There I make a new venv with `python3 -m venv ./venvLocal` and activate it. Next I run  `python3 -m pip install -r venv_requirements.txt`.

**The problem:** For multiple packages I get the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ... No matching distribution found for ...`.

**What I tried**: 1. The version of pip in the original venv was older that the one in my new venv. I downgraded pip to the same version as the original, but the problem persisted, 2. I installed the packages for which the stated version could not be found by hand with `pip install ..`. The installation worked fine, but when running my code afterwards I got many error messages that modules are not found or that there are problems within the modules.

**Further:** 1. `which pip` gives me (correctly) the one in my venv, 2. the original venv was created with exact the same command as the second one., 3. The original and new venv are on different (linux) machines, connected via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the problems: It was an issue with the python version: While I updated python to the same version as on the machine with the original venv, I did not change the symlink ([like eg. described here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/upgrade-python)) and thus the new environment had been made with the old python version.