# How can I copy python venv?

Tags: python, windows

I tried copying the entire `venv` folder to another computer and adding `C:\venv\Scripts` to windows environment variables, but typing python still gives me an error `No Python at 'C:\Python\python.exe'`

I can execute `Scripts\activate.bat` but I cannot excecute python code

Looking at the executables, they are only 500kb in size, and the entire scripts folder is 1.5mb.

Is this correct for a python executable, or does it contain calls or symlinks to the installed python executable elsewhere?

If not, why can I not launch python if I add the venv/Scripts folder to the Path and why do I get the `No Python at 'C:\Python\python.exe'` error?

I tried restarting command prompt and the PC altogether, I still get the same errors

Comment: why do you need to do this? Why not just create the files you need the venv and use the venv for interpretation?

Comment: I don't understand "why not just create the files you need the venv", I thought this was the purpose of Venv, so I can move the entire directory with interpreter and code between machines without worrying about keeping correct versions of libraries and python

Comment: so you are trying to transfer a venv between machines?

Comment: yes, the entire directory with code

Comment: have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438681/how-to-duplicate-virtualenv
I think it's what you need